# Error in dividing the columns and adding the result into a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe 'keep_df' as shown:

```
            DateTime             Modeled Flow(cfs)  Observed Flow(cfs) Seconds
   Event                
   Event 1  2016-08-15 15:35:00      11.85926               0.0         300.00
   Event 1  2016-08-15 10:05:00      30.05923               0.0         300.00
   Event 1  2016-08-15 10:00:00      31.10118               0.0         300.00
   Event 1  2016-08-15 09:55:00      32.17444               0.0         300.00
   Event 1  2016-08-15 09:50:00      33.25405               0.0         300.00
```

I wanted to create new columns which is got by dividing Modeled Flow (cfs) and also Observed flow (cfs) with Seconds column as shown below:

```
keep_df['Modelled Volume(f3)'] = keep_df['Modeled Flow(cfs)']/keep_df['Seconds']
keep_df['Observed Volume(f3)'] = keep_df['Observed Flow(cfs)']/keep_df['Seconds']
keep_df()
```

But after running the above i'm getting an error like this:

```
Type error: 'Dataframe' object is not callable
```

Since 'Seconds' column is default value i tried this:

```
keep_df['Modelled Volume(f3)'] = 'Modeled Flow (cfs)'/300.00
keep_df['Observed Volume(f3)'] = 'Observed Flow (cfs)'/300.00
keep_df()
```

But still i'm getting this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-b268c3093f01> in <module>()
 ----> 1 keep_df['Modelled Volume(f3)'] = 'Modeled Flow (cfs)'/300.00
  2 keep_df['Observed Volume(f3)'] = 'Observed Flow (cfs)'/300.00
  3 keep_df()

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'
```

What could i possibly do?

Comment: you called `keep_df()` you want just `keep_df` in your first bit of code

Comment: Since i'm using ipython notebook, '()' after the dataframe is used to run the code.

Comment: Well then you posted an incomplete question, you've posted an image, no raw data and complete code that others can run to reproduce your error, as such it makes things very difficult for others to help you and you waste our time

Comment: Sorry i'm new to this, now i have edited the question. Hope i am clear now.

Comment: you've still failed to post the complete code, you say `keep_df()` is a function which so me seems improbable but where is it?

Comment: I have added it. I meant to say '()' after the dataframe name is used to run the code in ipython. My complete code is given by those 3 lines.

Comment: I'm saying you shouldn't need the `()`, did you try without them?

Comment: Ok got it thank you.  Started with python n pandas just a week ago. Till now i used to run everything with '()'. Was working fine. I wasn't aware of it. Sorry if i wasted your time. I'm really grateful for your input. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `.div` instead

```
keep_df['Modelled Volume(f3)'] = keep_df['Modeled Flow(cfs)'].div(keep_df['Seconds'])
keep_df['Observed Volume(f3)'] = keep_df['Observed Flow(cfs)'].div(keep_df['Seconds'])
keep_df
```

Also for the second part

```
keep_df['Modelled Volume(f3)'] = keep_df['Modeled Flow(cfs)']/300.00
keep_df['Observed Volume(f3)'] = keep_df['Observed Flow(cfs)']/300.00
keep_df
```

Comment: @jezrael I see in the OP's initial `keep_df` has an indexing on event, so i'm guessing we should first do `keep_df.reset_index(inplace=True)` ?
Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: No, check [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42087695/error-in-dividing-the-columns-and-adding-the-result-into-a-new-column#comment71347187_42087695) - it is necessary remove, because it is dataframe name no function

Comment: @jezrael Appreciated,Learnt a lot from you.